# How to position a child component in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to position my bottomnavbar to the bottom of my screen, but is is not working? 
I've been trying to set the position to absolute and then bottom: 0, but if I do it in the app.js component on  or do it straight in the stylesheet of the bottomNavbar.js component, none of it works.

here is my app.js component:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

class BottomNavbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>insights</Text>
        <Text>Incidents</Text>
        <Text>PLUS</Text>
        <Text>Team Alerts</Text>
        <Text>More</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
  },
});
export default BottomNavbar;
```

**And here is my BottomNavbar component:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

class BottomNavbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>insights</Text>
        <Text>Incidents</Text>
        <Text>PLUS</Text>
        <Text>Team Alerts</Text>
        <Text>More</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
  },
});
export default BottomNavbar;
```

Now I would like the bottomnavbar to show up at the bottom of the phonescreen, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

class BottomNavbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>insights</Text>
        <Text>Incidents</Text>
        <Text>PLUS</Text>
        <Text>Team Alerts</Text>
        <Text>More</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.appContainer}>
        {/* ...other components */}
        <BottomNavbar />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  appContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: 80,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => App);
```